# how trigger client's localhost socket from a web application

Tags: java, sockets

I have my web application deployed in cloud. When a user access the application from his system , and click on a trigger button. I want to trigger the local host socket. Is this possible through java.

```
public String trigger() {

  String ipServer = "localhost";
  int port = 5555;
  String resp="";
  try {
    Socket socekt = new Socket(ipServer, port);
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socekt.getOutputStream());
    dataOut.writeUTF("[TRIGGER]");
    BufferedReader resReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socekt.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String str;
    while ((str = resReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(str.contains("RECIV")){
            resp = str;
        }
    }
    dataOut.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e);
  }
  return resp;

}
```

This code is working fine when run as a desktop application, but when I deploy the code it in the cloud as web application, I wont work as it cant be able to connect to clients localhost. Can any one suggest me how to do it in java?

CONTEXT:
I have a desktop application which runs in the users localhost and listens to port 5555. I am building a web application which is deployed in cloud. When User access this application from his browser and click on trigger button. I will trigger the desktop application and the cloud application will get the response.

Comment: Connect to client's localhost? If it's deployed on a cloud server, localhost is in the cloud. It's a completely different scenario than running it as an application on your desktop computer.

Comment: Yes I want to connect to clients localhost using java any suggestions?

Comment: Why would the client accept a connection from your webapp? That's like opening a door to strangers. Do you understand what `localhost` is?

Comment: Will it work If I use some client end technology like socket.io ?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do.  What's the execution context of this code?  How does it get deployed "in the cloud"?  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I have a desktop application which runs in the users localhost and listens to port 5555. I am building a web application which is deployed in cloud. When User access this application from his browser and click on trigger button. I will trigger the desktop application and the cloud application will get the response.

Comment: If you have software running in the cloud, it's the server. The clients connect to it, the server won't connect anywhere, it will only accept connections. Your "trigger button" approach is flawed.

Comment: What's the reason for this kind of mechanism? Why do you need to click on the trigger button? What's the end goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a application which works as a local server and listens to the port 5555, I have device which works only with this desktop application. To active the device I have to send to send a message to this local server. This sending message I want to do it from another application which is in cloud. It may not be possible to connect from cloud server to local server, but i am trying if socket.io may work as it is a client technology.

Comment: You should initiate the connections from the desktop application. Clicking on a button on the serverside is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, triggering part I can do it from desktop but I am trying to do it from server side because this device once activated will gives a response which i want to save in my server database.

Comment: No. Click on a button on your desktop application. It will get the data from the device. Then it will send the data to the server. No buttons on the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130144/discussion-between-java-developer-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it will be impossible to connect to a raw socket from a internet web application, but this blog very helpful.

http://artemyankov.com/tcp-client-for-browsers/
https://github.com/yankov/webtcp

By using bridge I am now able to connect to a raw socket.

[image]